# Azure Function - Programmatically checking its done

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-monitoring

I have an Azure Function that I would like to check if it has finished running.

At the moment, what I'm doing is going into the app in the Portal, then clicking on Monitor and watching the date/time until it basically stops showing new rows. Basically if after 10 mins theres been no entry I know its done.

[image]

This isn't really ideal so is there anyway I can do this check in JavaScript instead?

Alternatively some easier way in the Portal? I've seen it possible to run queries in in Logs (Analytics) within Application Insights? Anything there that can do the trick?

Any ideas/help would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: why you need to check it's done? function like queue-trigger, timer-trigger may run continuously.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a sample request that would return the same thing as JSON -

```
curl 'https://management.azure.com//subscriptions/<SUBSCRIPTION_ID>/resourceGroups/<RESOURCE_GROUP>/providers/microsoft.insights/components/<FUNC_APP_NAME>/api/query?api-version=2015-05-01' \
    -H 'Authorization: Bearer eyJ0....' \
    -H 'Content-Type: application/json' \
    -H 'Accept: application/json' \
    --data-binary $'{\n  "query": "requests | where timestamp >= ago(30d) | where cloud_RoleName =~ \'<FUNC_APP_NAME>\' and operation_Name == \'<FUNC_NAME>\' | summarize count=count() by success"\n}'
```

For a more detailed view, use -

```
"query": "requests |
    project timestamp, id, operation_Name, success, resultCode, duration, operation_Id, cloud_RoleName, invocationId=customDimensions['InvocationId'] |
    where timestamp > ago(30d) |
    where cloud_RoleName =~ '<FUNC_APP_NAME>' and operation_Name == '<FUNC_NAME>' |
    order by timestamp desc |
    take 20"
```

**Source:** F12 Developer Tools > Network tab while in the Azure Portal refreshing the blade from your screenshot.

To be more elegant i would recommend you query the [Application Insights API](https://dev.applicationinsights.io/quickstart) for this data, not ARM API.

Telemetry may be delayed for up to 5 minutes, it's usually much less but just account for that. Also be aware that `400 Bad Request` is treated as successful, all green, because technically that's correct, your function ran fine, it just got bad input -

[image: 400 bad request]

Comment: Ah thats looking like exactly what I was after.
I presume I can just paste that query directly in Application Insights?

Comment: Yes, it's a Kuso language query.

Comment: Also that query above its doing a check for the last 30 days? I keep getting 0 results found. Is the `and operation_Name` needed?

Comment: At the top of that execution status list in the portal blade you have a `Run in Application Insights` link. Click on it and it will generate the exact query that showed you the UI results.

Comment: Thanks - the above did the trick.
I'll just set the time to `where timestamp > ago(30m)` - if I get 0 results returned I guess I can assume its finished/not doing anything. Does that sound valid?

Comment: That will give you all runs that were successful or not with a 30 minute window view into the past WITHOUT the latest ~5 minutes. If that's ok, you're ok :)

Comment: Yep - and just for my understanding not the latest ~5 mins just because thats just Azure's delay?

Comment: It's a multi-tenant, distributed service built for scale. Some penalty comes with that, in this case in the form of ingest delay.

Comment: It may be worth exploring the Kudu API as well, maybe there's an endpoint that gives you roughly the same thing, real-time - https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Functions-API -- scratch that, i took a look, there's no execution API.